# Foreach loop to get appropriate List

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

I have next Java class:

```
public class Process {

private String id;
private String name;
private Date date;
private String status;

// getterr and setters and constructor
```

In main class I need to inicialize objects like this:

```
List<Process> processList = new ArrayList<>();

    Process process1 = new Process();
    process1.setId("1111");
    process1.setName("Step one under first status");
    process1.setDate(new Date());
    process1.setStatus("");

    Process process2 = new Process();
    process2.setId("1111");
    process2.setName("Step two under first status");
    process2.setDate(new Date());
    process2.setStatus("");

    Process process3 = new Process();
    process3.setId("1111");
    process3.setName("");
    process3.setDate(new Date());
    process3.setStatus("Status One");

    Process process4 = new Process();
    process4.setId("1111");
    process4.setName("Step one under second status");
    process4.setDate(new Date());
    process4.setStatus("");

    Process process5 = new Process();
    process5.setId("1111");
    process5.setName("");
    process5.setDate(new Date());
    process5.setStatus("Status two");

    Process process6 = new Process();
    process6.setId("2222");
    process6.setName("Step one under first status");
    process6.setDate(new Date());
    process6.setStatus("");

    Process process7 = new Process();
    process7.setId("2222");
    process7.setName("Step two under first status");
    process7.setDate(new Date());
    process7.setStatus("");

    Process process8 = new Process();
    process8.setId("2222");
    process8.setName("");
    process8.setDate(new Date());
    process8.setStatus("Status One");

    processList.add(process1);
    processList.add(process2);
    processList.add(process3);
    processList.add(process4);
    processList.add(process5);
    processList.add(process6);
    processList.add(process7);
    processList.add(process8);
```

From that list i need to get a new list with objects like this:

first object (id = "1111", name = "Step one under first status", date, "Status One")

second object (id = "1111", name = "Step two under first status", date, "Status One")

third object(id = "1111", name = "Step one under second status", date, "Status two")

fourth object(id = "2222", name = "Step one under first status", date, "Status One")

fifth object(id = "2222", name = "Step two under first status", date, "Status One")

Thank you for help and sorry for bad English (it's not my native language) :)

EDIT:

Hi. I dont need to remove items. I need to combine them (with foreach loop for example) to get items with all data. For example: process1 (with id = "1111") have name but it doesnt have status. process3 (id ="1111") have status "Status One" but doesnt have name. So the result of that need to be: first object (id = "1111", name = "Step one under first status", date, "Status One")

process2 (id = "1111") also have name, but doesnt have status. So i need to combine them with process3 (id ="1111"). The result will be: second object (id = "1111", name = "Step two under first status", date, "Status One")...

etc.

process7 have another id = "2222". It have a name = "Step two under first status" but doesnt hava a status, so i need to combine them with process8  (id ="2222") who's got status. Result of that will be: fifth object(id = "2222", name = "Step two under first status", date, "Status One")

Comment: what is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand what you mean , but if you want to remove some items (Status = "")from your list :

processList.removeIf(e -> e.getStatus().equals("");

Hi. I dont need to remove items. I need to combine them (with foreach loop for example) to get item with all data. For example: process1 (with id = "1111#) have name but it doesnt have status. process3 have status "Status One" but doesnt have name. So the result of that need to be: first object (id = "1111", name = "Step one under first status", date, "Status One")

process2 (id = "1111") also have name, but doesnt have status. So i need to combine them with process3. The result will be: second object (id = "1111", name = "Step two under first status", date, "Status One")...

etc.

process7 have another id = "2222". It have a name = "Step two under first status" but doesnt hava a status, so i need to combine them with process8 who's got status. Result of that will be: fifth object(id = "2222", name = "Step two under first status", date, "Status One")

Answer (score 0):

ok thanks for the clarification , it seems pretty easy :

```
List<Process> resultList = new ArrayList<Process>();

Iterator<Process> i = processList.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
  Process p = i.next(); // must be called before you can call i.remove()

  if(p.getStatus().isEmpty()) {
    
    for (Process currentProcess : processList) {
      
      if(!currentProcess.getStatus().isEmpty()) {
        p.setStatus(currentProcess.getStatus());
        
        resultList.add(p);
        break;
      }
    
    }
  } 
   i.remove();
}   

System.out.println(resultList);
```

Then you should have :

Process [name=Step one under first status, id=1111, date=Tue Feb 09 19:32:04 CET 2021, status=Status One],
Process [name=Step two under first status, id=1111, date=Tue Feb 09 19:32:04 CET 2021, status=Status One],
Process [name=Step one under second status, id=1111, date=Tue Feb 09 19:32:04 CET 2021, status=Status two],
Process [name=Step one under first status, id=2222, date=Tue Feb 09 19:32:04 CET 2021, status=Status One],
Process [name=Step two under first status, id=2222, date=Tue Feb 09 19:32:04 CET 2021, status=Status One]